# git - remote branch "apparently" not deleted

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

Developer A creates remote branch

```
git checkout -b myBranch
git push -u origin myBranch
```

Developer B checks it out

```
git fetch origin myBranch
git checkout myBranch
```

They both do some work, commit, pull, etc. When they are done, merge back to develop

```
git checkout develop
git merge --no-ff myBranch
git push origin develop
```

and delete branch

```
# Developer A
git branch -d myBranch             # delete local branch
git push origin --delete myBranch  # delete remote branch

# Developer B
git branch -d myBranch
git fetch
```

At this point, only Developer A who pushed the remote delete can see the correct state of remote. Developer B still sees that myBranch on remote, even though it no longer exists. If Developer B tries to check out myBranch and pull, gets a 'cannot find myBranch ref' error.

```
#Developer A
git branch -a
  * develop
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/develop
  remotes/origin/develop
  remotes/origin/production

#Developer B
git branch -a
  * develop
  remotes/origin/myBranch                 # <<<<< why is this line here??
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/develop
  remotes/origin/develop
  remotes/origin/production
```

If we go on bitBucket web console and look at the repo, branch 'myBranch' does not exist.

What's going on here and why, how do we solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Developer B needs to use the -p parameter on git fetch.

`git fetch -p`

This parameter will remove all references that do not exist on remote.

Comment: is it possible to remove references that do not exist on remote without doing a generic fetch? I dislike fetching without specifying a branch because that usually brings back a lot of branches that I'm not interested in.

Comment: It should be possible using `git remote prune origin`.

Answer (score 1):

> git branch -a

`-a` stand for all branches (local + remote) this is why the user see all the branches.

> Developer B still sees that myBranch on remote, even though it no longer exists

You should execute: `git fetch --all --prune`
The prune will remove all local copies of your branches, tags which are removed from the server.

---

You can set the prune value to be your default so it will remove the deleted branches and tags on every fetch

```
git config fetch.prune true
```

---

#### -p / --prune

> After fetching, remove any remote-tracking references that no longer exist on the remote.
>
> Tags are not subject to pruning if they are fetched only because of the default tag auto-following or due to a -`-tag` option.
>
> However, if tags are fetched due to an explicit refspec (either on the command line or in the remote configuration, for example if the remote was cloned with the --mirror option), then **they are also subject to pruning**.

Comment: It's hard to decide which to award as correct. All the details are useful and I especially the option to set as default, however I think on a daily basis I will end up using `git fetch -p` as it's shorter to remember and type. Hence the choice to award the other answer. I did however upvote yours to reward the extra effort

Comment: btw, do you know if it's possible to remove references that do not exist on remote without doing a generic fetch? I dislike fetching without specifying a branch because that usually brings back a lot of branches that I'm not interested in.

Comment: Fetch is the command which update (sync) the local repo with the remote one so you can't avoid it.

Comment: `git remote prune origin` does it apparently as suggested above by Filip. I'm just adding it here for other people that might be reading and looking to achieve the same

Comment: It will do the same as `git remote prune origin` = `git fetch --all` will havethe same outcome